# jQuery's attr - return multiple classes not just the 1st

Tags: jquery, class, attributes

Given a div such as:

```
<div class="widget block dock clock">yada yada</div>
```

I'd like to be abe to use JQUERY's `$(div).attr('class');`

to find all the classes, but the JQUERY.attr only return widget. Is there a way with JQUERY to return all the classes defined for the element?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery `attr` should return the entire string.  Are you sure your code is correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you have currently will work, [here's a quick demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820916/jquerys-attr-return-multiple-classes-not-just-the-1st):

```
alert($("div").attr("class"));​ //alerts "widget block dock clock"
```

Something to keep in mind is that [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns that attribute on **the first matched element**, from the docs:

> It's important to note that the `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the **first** element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, we need to rely on a looping construct such as jQuery's `.each()` method.

So for example, something like this:

```
<div class="widget">yada yada</div>
<div class="widget block dock clock">yada yada</div>​
```

Would alert only `"widget"`, since that's the class of the *first* matching element.

Answer (score 5):

Nick mentioned using **.each()**...

...but...an easier way might be to iterate via **.split()**:

```
(this).attr("class").split(" ")
```

...then you are just dealing with a *plain old* javascript string array

Answer (score 2):

.attr('class') will return all classes defined for the element. Visual style is not only defined by the classes but also by css properties. You might also want to poll for them with .css('param-name')

Answer (score 2):

**[Yup, it returns all](http://jsbin.com/atuce)**