# Creating and using jQuery Variables from html Link class

Tags: jquery, html, class, variables, jquery-selectors

Only just starting out with jQuery and I'm sure this is basic stuff for those that know, but I can't get it working.

I have a very simple and repetitive script that I'm trying to streamline, that changes the background colour of a background div, when certain links are hovered. i.e. each link has an associated  background div.

```
$('div#navigation a.A').hover(function(){
$('div#bg-nav .A').addClass('bg-active');
},function(){
$('div#bg-nav .A').removeClass('bg-active');
});;

$('div#navigation a.B').hover(function(){
$('div#bg-nav .B').addClass('bg-active');
},function(){
$('div#bg-nav .B').removeClass('bg-active');
});;
```

This is repeated for each link. Links and the background divs are created dynamically by the CMS so manually updating this script every time a page is added isn't ideal. And I can't use pure CSS because of where the links are in relation to the divs within the page structure.

As there is an obvious pattern, (the background divs have the same class as the trigger links), I figured it must be possible to use the class of the link being hovered to affect the relevant div, passing the variable onto the selectors, something like below, but as a newb I can't get it working!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var linkClass = $(this).attr("class");
$("div#navigation a").hover(function() {
$('div#bg-nav.'+ linkClass).addClass('bg-active');
},function(){
$('div#bg-nav.'+ linkClass).removeClass('bg-active');
});;
```

Comment: You have many unexpected `;` --> `});;` --> `});`

Comment: Am *very new* to javascripting!... and have ordered a book to learn! Thought I'd be able to figure this one out reading up online but have failed! Any pointers on how you would achieve this? Are the unexpected characters preventing this from working, or am I million miles off the mark? Thank you!

Comment: There's not much to the html tbh, basic unordered navigation list, where each link has a unique class, then what I've referred to as the background divs are just elements elsewhere in the document that have matching classes to the links. e.g. link a.classA should affect div# .classA when hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. Also take a look at **Density 21.5's** answer for details.

```
$('#navigation a').hover(function () {
    $('#bg-nav').find('.'+ $(this).attr('class')).toggleClass('bg-active');
});
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you everybody. I knew it was more simple than I was making it! Can't wait until I'm able to achieve this sort of thing myself!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to move the line

`var linkClass = $(this).attr("class");`

inside the hover call. In your version $(this) refers to $(document).

Second, this will only work if your `$('div#navigation a')` items have the 'A' or 'B' class **as their first (or only) class**, otherwise you will have to cycle through all classes with each() and find a way to select the correct class.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820916/jquerys-attr-return-multiple-classes-not-just-the-1st) question for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

if u post ur html it wud be more helpful , however if I guessed right this code should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var linkclass;
     $('#id_of_link').on('click',function(){
        linkclass = $(this).attr('class');      
     });
     $("div#navigation a").hover(function() {
        $('div#bg-nav.').find(linkclass).addClass('bg-active');
        },function(){
           $('div#bg-nav.').find(linkclass).removeClass('bg-active');
        });
});
```

use `.delegate()` if using < jQuery 1.7
otherwise use `.on()`