# Image src replace not working

Tags: javascript

I have an accordion menu that the active link drops down the menu, loads an external page into a `div`, then changes the banner on the same click. I have everything working except for the banner image changing out. I thought I had the code right, but something seems to be missing, and I can't figure it out.

Here is my html:

```
<section id="commercialBanner">
    <img src="images/catalog/indoorBanner.jpg"/>
</section>  

<section id="accordionNav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="indoorEntrance" class="category"><a class="ext" id="indoor" href="montage.html">Indoor Entrance</a>
            <ul id="indoorEntranceSubmenu" class="sideSub">
                <li><a href="montage.html" class="ext">Ecomat Squares</a></li>
                <li><a href="gatekeeper.html" class="ext">Gatekeeper</a></li>
                <li><a href="absorba.html" class="ext">Absorba</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="outdoorEntrance" class="category"><a id="outdoor" class="ext" href="aquaFlow.html">Outdoor Mats</a>
            <ul id="outdoorEntranceSubmenu" class="sideSub">
                <li><a href="aquaFlow.html" class="ext" id="aquaflow">AquaFlow</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <section id="catalog"></section>
```

Here is my Script:

```
$('a.ext').click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $('#catalog').load(this.href);
});

$('.category > a').click(function(evt) {                 
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
        $('#nav li ul').hide();
        $(this).next().show()
        // $(this).next('li > a').trigger('click')
        $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    };
    if ($('#indoor').attr('class') == 'active'){
        $("#commercialBanner img").attr("src", "images/catalog/indoorBanner.jpg");
    };  
    if ($('#outdoor').attr('class') == 'active'){
        $("#commercialBanner img").attr("src", "images/catalog/outdoorBanner.jpg");
    };  
});
```

Comment: Is this all of the code? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: You should be using `hasClass("active")`

Comment: Use `alert()` or `console.log()` to make sure those lines are called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be checking the class attribute incorrectly - you have more than one class on an element, so:

```
$('#indoor').attr('class') is 'ext active' or 'ext'
```

As noted by @epascarello: use hasClass("active").

See this:

[jQuery's attr - return multiple classes not just the 1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820916/jquerys-attr-return-multiple-classes-not-just-the-1st)